# Is 12.5 percent wrong way of expression?

Tags: punctuation, numbers

[image]

From IELTS mock exam. I am not aware of any reason why 12.5 percent is marked wrong. Would someone pelease enlighten me?

Edit: One of the comments said that percent should not be spelled out.  I happened to be reading the 538 blog and it seems the 538 blogger doesn't share this view( although it could be argued that blog is not considered "serious" media.[image]

Comment: Maybe that's because no one writes the word "percent" after a number, the symbol <%> is usually written instead. In your screenshot, the line at the very bottom is the correct answers, isn't it?

Comment: @YellowSky it is. Is it really that unusual to spell out the percent symbol

Comment: It is really unusual. You spell it out mainly when you talk about it, e.g. at school at a math class explaining how to calculate that, or in a math textbook, but not when you present statistic information. The symbol <%> is an ideogram, it saves a lot of space on paper and greatly facilitates perception of statistic data.

Comment: Ok, good to know.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: The common style is to write either *12.5%* or *twelve-and-a-half percent*. The symbol is paired with a numeral, and the word with a written-out number. However, that's just a common style. It doesn't mean it's objectively wrong to do it differently—unless you're strictly following a particular style guide. IELTS might follow a particular style, but I don't know that.

Comment: I wonder whether it's computer marked and only one way of writing it has been entered into the database. If that's the case then 12.5 percent  would not match 12.5% even though they are exactly the same value and meaning. Similarly "twelve and a half percent" or "one eighth" wouldn't match either.